# Retrieving the COM error in Visual Studio

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, office-interop

i want to ask about coding VB.NET to export the data from datagridview into excel file..

last month it work completely fine..after left for a month it went so many error.. i never change a coding or reference in visual studio

[image]

This is the error that popup when i trying to export into the excel..i don't know if it about reference or about office .

thank you

Comment: At a guess, it’s likely the references to office that have been updated.  I suggest you might be better off using any of the many 3rd party tools for excel exporting.  EPPlus comes to mind.  Much more robust solution rather than fragile office interops

Comment: @Hursey is that mean that i need to change a code if i using EPPlus or just add the EPPlus in nugget package? (sorry i new )

Comment: Yeah, there is a bit of restructuring but it’s very well documented and pretty easy to use

Comment: There are quite a few options via nugets.  EPPlus is just one of the, other tools might fit your situation better

Comment: is there any way to fix this problem without changing it?

Comment: Try removing the references for office and re adding them, clean and rebuild, if still no go try deleting the bin folder

Comment: @Hursey nope still the same error

Comment: Well I would say that's unfortunate then.  Quick google for CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE suggests you're attempting to do something un-supported via office automation.   Sooo... that would mean maybe something has happen outside the scope of the code you've posted has changed (Pro-tip, posting images of code and errors is one sure fire way to get downvotes).  All in all though, If I was in your situation after all the bad experiences I've had, the last thing I would do is use Office.Interops because this type of thing just plain happens and is outside the control of your app

Comment: @Hursey thank you... i take ur advice using EPP and its work...got a lot of changing but it work..thank you